# Memory leak when reading an S3 object with AWS Lambda using the AWS Lambda C++ runtime

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-cpp

I am reading an S3 object with AWS Lambda using the AWS Lambda C++ runtime. I use this function:

```
void s3read(const std::string& bucket, const std::string& key, const std::string& filename_local) {
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration client_conf;
    client_conf.region = Aws::Environment::GetEnv("AWS_REGION");
    client_conf.caFile = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt";
    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(client_conf);
    Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest object_request;
    object_request.WithBucket(bucket.c_str()).WithKey(key.c_str());
    auto get_object_outcome = s3_client.GetObject(object_request);
    if(get_object_outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        auto &retrieved_file = get_object_outcome.GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody();
        Aws::OFStream local_file;
        local_file.open(filename_local.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        local_file << retrieved_file.rdbuf(); // Leak
        local_file.close();
    };
    std::remove(filename_local.c_str()); // For leak testing purposes
};
```

It works fine. However, the *Max Memory Used* keeps growing if I call the Lambda repeatedly. The leak seems to come from *rdbuf()*, but I don't know how to solve it.

**Update:**
There is no leak when *filename_local* is */dev/null*.

Comment: What makes you so sure that `retrieved_file.rdbuf();` leaks? Any evidence?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If I comment that line, there is no leak.

Comment: I'd recommend you use a tool like `valgrind` to check what's the exact reason. IMO there's no guarantee that `Aws::OFStream` doesn't leak.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have the same problem with std::ofstream